# Is there any possibility to grab html content along with the attributes and methods like onChange ,onClick

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml

By using the methods like `$("#id").html()` can grab only basic html code.
But is there any way to grab the html content along with the methods and other stuff?

Comment: I would assume it depends entirely on how the events are bound.  If the events were created using the inline html attributes, or maybe even using the DOM properties for the attributes, getting the html of the element I would assume would show the attributes defined on them.

Comment: Though testing, it **does not** show the methods attached with say `element.onchange = function(){};`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, doing this:

```js
    var element = $("#id");
    console.dir(element);
```

will show you every property/method of the element.

Comment: That will show you every jquery property/method.  You'll need `var element = $("#id")[0];` to get the DOM element.

Comment: This is very true ^

Answer (score 0):

Basically, once you have a reference to `$("#id").html()` you can access all the required properties via [.attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [.prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

EDIT:

as you said you need to get the whole element as text:

```
$('#id').clone().prop('outerHTML')
```

Comment: Actually i'm in a situation to grab all the html content and then place it in a new file.

Comment: The methods to these html elements are already written in the js file linked to it.

Comment: so when i place the html content the methods attached are removed.

Comment: @Taplar  Yes, that would probably be the best practice, edited the answer.

Comment: thanks but its giving same result as of the html() method

Comment: @Eswara nadh are you sure? .html() and .prop('outerHTML') do different things

Comment: Yes both are giving same html content with no attributes or methods

Comment: can you edit the post and add your relevant HTML tree?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy html data with onclick function calling 
use jquery `clone()` function

```js
 

    function test(){
        
         var data = $(".foo").clone();
         $(".test").html(data);
    }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  
<html>
<body>
<div class="foo">
<h2  onclick="test()">Click here to copy data</h2>

</div>
<div class="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```